# What Golang function could be used to enforce a minimum code coverage and return an Exit1 if false?

Tags: code-coverage, go

Follow-up to [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10516662/2777965).

How to ensure that a certain minimal code coverage is reached in Golang? E.g. if the CI runs, the build should fail if the code coverage is less than X percent.

In Java, one could use Jacoco and define a minimum code coverage. Other language like Python support minimum code coverage as well.

One option is to simply create a bash script that parsers the output of `go test -cover`, but I would like to know if there is a off the shelf solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There aren't any off the shelf solution currently that allows you to specify a variable number of code coverage percentage.

There is the tool [Courtney](https://github.com/dave/courtney) which enforces 100% code coverage. This tool also allows you to comment on blocks of code which do not need to be covered.

Comment: I like this idea. [However the author of this tool has not been convinced yet to publish an executable](https://github.com/dave/courtney/issues/13), but perhaps my setup is wrong at the moment. Perhaps you could explain how you enabled this tool on your computer?

Comment: @030 The assumption with the tool is you have Go installed on your system. If you do a `go get` for the tool, it will automatically install an executable of Courtney for you. Depending on how you have your $PATH variable set, you should be able to execute the command using either just `courtney` or `$GOPATH/bin/courtney`

This is standard functionality for all go modules that have a `package main`.